# How could I bind docker container to specific external interface

Tags: docker

I have two network interfaces, `eth0` and `eth1`,

How could I bind all docker container to `eth1`, and let all network traffic go out and in via the `eth1`

Thanks~

## update

I tried to bind to the `eth1` with 133.130.60.36.

But i still got no luck, i still get the eth0 IP as the public IP in the container. the network flow is not go out via eth1

```
➜  ~  docker run -d --name Peach_1 -p 133.130.60.36::9998 -ti sample/ubuntu-vnc-selenium-firefox

➜  ~  docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                 COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                     NAMES
eb28f0d1c337        sample/ubuntu-vnc-selenium-firefox   "/opt/bin/run_sele_s   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        5901/tcp, 133.130.60.36:32768->9998/tcp   Peach_1

➜  ~  docker exec -ti Peach_1 zsh

➜  /  curl ipecho.net/plain ; echo
133.130.101.114
```

Comment: It's years later but have you found a solution yet? I am facing the same issue on a Mac host and I don't think the solution posted by Yogesh_D work on my machine.

Answer (score 56):

Here's something from the docker docs

https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/

> If you want to be more restrictive and only allow container services
>   to be contacted through a specific external interface on the host
>   machine, you have two choices. When you invoke docker run you can use
>   either `-p IP:host_port:container_port` or `-p IP::port` to specify the
>   external interface for one particular binding.
>   Or if you always want Docker port forwards to bind to one specific IP address, you can edit your system-wide Docker server
>   settings and add the option `--ip=IP_ADDRESS`. Remember to restart your
>   Docker server after editing this setting.

Comment: Hi @Yogesh_D the tutorial looks abstract for me, how could I bind all the contianers to eth1, currently i start up the container in the command `docker run -d --name Project_1  -p 9998  -ti sample/ubuntu-vnc-selenium-firefox` thanks so much

Comment: The excerpt above gives you exactly that..  -p IP:host_port:container_port or -p IP::port.. this is what you need to do..

Comment: thanks for your support, i tried your solution but it still failed.

Comment: Thanks Yogesh! This is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Try this one: https://medium.com/@havloujian.joachim/advanced-docker-networking-outgoing-ip-921fc3090b09

Answer (score 7):

Putting IP in `-p` only works for traffic that comes to server, for traffic that leaving server you can assign static local IP to each container, Then change source IP in `iptables` or `snat`. Here is a sample iptables rule:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -p all -s 172.20.128.2 ! -d 172.20.128.2 -j SNAT --to-source YourInterfaceIP
```

Comment: How would this be possible for ALL containers? Preferrable with UFW?

Comment: What does the 172.20.128.2 IP corresponds to?

Comment: @CDuv It's static IP for the container in docker network.

Comment: @Ybrin if you run containers in default bridge network just use `iptables -t nat POSTROUTING -p all -s 172.17.0.0/16 -j SNAT --to-source <yourInterfaceIP>` where `172.17.0.0/16` is the default bridge driver subnet.