# Docker container prefer host eth0 over wlan0 for internet

Tags: routes, docker, docker-network

How do I start up a docker container so that it will use the host's eth0 and not wlan when both are available?  I want the container to use my wired connection at the office directly to access network resources and not be affected by the host's network settings that allow me access the internet over wifi.

Host is ubuntu 14.04, container is ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Try having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32052975/how-could-i-bind-docker-container-to-specific-external-interface