# How do i bind Docker container to a specific external IP address, if i need to allocate many ports?

Tags: docker

related to [How could I bind docker container to specific external interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32052975/how-could-i-bind-docker-container-to-specific-external-interface) , but a harder case.

i have a server machine with 10 IP addresses (on 1 bonded interface, looking like 10 lo:x interfaces). If i launch docker instances by supplying IP address to bind to like

-p IP:port:port
or
-p IP:port:port/udp

it works, and i get expected results, incoming connection to specified IP address go to the specified docker container.

but the problem is, i need the containers to operate a wide range of UDP ports (16K), for WebRTC media streaming, that Docker can't allocate so many ports, it just hangs (a well-known and well-described problem, -p with a range of ports works only as long is range is under 1000-2000, 16000 won't work).

i can work around it with --net=host, but it breaks the IP thing: every container binds to every IP then.

is there any way around that? or all i can do is installing a full virtualization system and use virtual machines instead of docker containers (which will be a headache to do and pain in the ass to maintain, especially since i will need several servers).

effectively, i am looking for a way to completely redirect some network interface to the Docker instance. what shall i do if i have a Docker instance "fe2ce5b3de59", launched with --net=none (which provides a clean sheet), interface lo:0, and i want everyting that comes into any TCP or UDP port of lo:0 to go into the same port of container's interface, and back, with the container being fully in the open?

Comment: I think the solution should come from outside of the docker.  I would check `iptables` and would configure routing on the host side. Also I believe it has an option `--in-interface` which can help you with your setup.

Comment: that kind of makes more questions that solves... can you please elaborate?