# Docker: limit VPN to single container

Tags: docker, docker-network

My docker host has multiple network cards, though the same network

`- Card1: 192.168.0.50`

`- Card2: 192.168.0.55`

I am connecting to a VPN from container 1 but not from container 2.

Once VPN is connected on container 1 both containers have the new IP.

Is there a way to limit VPN to only single container and not affect the other ?

Comment: This question seems related [Routing from docker containers using a different physical network interface and default gateway](http://serverfault.com/questions/696747/routing-from-docker-containers-using-a-different-physical-network-interface-and)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How could I bind docker container to specific external interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32052975/how-could-i-bind-docker-container-to-specific-external-interface)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using --net host on the container which caused this issue, as the VPN was now active on host and all containers affected. OpenVPN just on a container without net host works perfectly fine.