# Azure Edge Module Multiple IP Addresses

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge

I have server with 2 Network cards (2xIP). Is it possible to bind an Azure Edge module (Docker) to a specific IP address? If yes, how? I cannot find much.

Comment: Have you tried to play which bridge network docker is using?

Comment: OK, you did not find much.  But what did you find so far?

Comment: Unfortunately we are having a problem with server OS so we cannot test it yet. But beside that what i have found also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32052975/how-could-i-bind-docker-container-to-specific-external-interface that I could assign it via -p IP:host_port:container_port. Am i right?